# How not to parse some fields by logstash?

Tags: json, ruby, string, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a log-file which looks like this (simplified):

```
 { "startDate": "2015-05-27", "endDate": "2015-05-27", 
    "request" : {"requestId":"123","field2":1,"field2": 2,"field3":3, ....} }
```

Log-stash tries to `parse` all fields including field "request". But is it possible not to parse this field?
I want to see the "request" field in `elastic-search` but it shouldn't be parsed.

here is a part of my config file:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "json"
        path => [
                "/var/log/service/restapi.log"
        ]
        tags => ["restapi"]
    }
}

filter {
    ruby {
        init => "require 'socket'"
        code => "
           event['host'] = Socket.gethostname.gsub(/\..*/, '')
           event['request'] = (event['request'].to_s);
        "
    }

    if "restapi" in [tags] {
        json {
            source => "message"
        }
        date {
                match => [ "date_start", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                target => "date_start"
         }
        date {
                match => [ "date_end", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                target => "date_end"
        }
        date {
                match => [ "date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                target => "date"
        }
    }
}
output {
    if "restapi" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["......."]
            template_name => "logs"
            template => "/etc/logstash/templates/service.json"
            template_overwrite => true
            index => "service-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            idle_flush_time => 20
            flush_size => 500
        }
    }
}
```

here is my template file:

```
{
  "template" : "service-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index": {
            "refresh_interval": "60s",
            "number_of_shards": 6,
            "number_of_replicas": 2
        }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "logs" : {
        "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dateOptionalTime" },
        "@version" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "message": { "type" : "string", "norms" : { "enabled" : false } },
        "method" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "traffic_source" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "request_path" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "status" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "host_name" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "environment" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "action" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "request_id" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "date" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dateOptionalTime" },
        "date_start" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dateOptionalTime" },
        "date_end" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dateOptionalTime" },
        "adnest_type" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "request" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is from logstash.log

```
response=>{"create"=>{"_index"=>"logs-2017.02.08", "_type"=>"json", "_id"=>"AVoeNgdhD5iEO87EVF_n", "status" =>400, "error"=> "type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [request]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"unknown property [requestId]" }}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

Comment: it's not quite clear what you are asking.  Are you asking to see "request" equal to a string version of that json object?

Comment: Logstash doesn't do very much that you don't ask it to do.  Including the basics of your config in your question would help.  Also, defining what you mean by "parsing" would clarify the question.  Also, are you looking at elasticsearch itself, or using kibana (which represents things its own way sometimes).

Comment: @Alcanzar, yes, i think, that json-value of field "request" ins string will be enough for me

Comment: @Alain Collins , i've add my logstash template file. About "parsing" - just see the string from logstash.log (updated the topic)

Comment: There's a lot going on here.  The part of your config that you posted has nothing to do with the parsing of the data you're asking about (and is probably better solved with mutate->gsub anyway).  The error you're getting from elasticsearch is because logstash is sending json into your string field.  Can you share any portion of your config that affects the "request" field (perhaps your input stanza has a json codec, or you have a json filter, etc).

Comment: @Alain Collins, i've added my full configs. Is there any problem?

Comment: The key to your config is that you're using the json filter, which will treat your message as json and make all the fields you're seeing.  There isn't a good way to *prevent* that, but @Alcanzar shows you a way to *reverse* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a ruby filter:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        init => "require 'socket'"
        code => "
           event['host'] = Socket.gethostname.gsub(/\..*/, '')
           event['request'] = (event['request'].to_s);
        "
    }

    if "restapi" in [tags] {
        ruby {
                code => '
                    require "json"
                    event.set("request",event.get("request").to_json)'
        }
        date {
                match => [ "date_start", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                target => "date_start"
         }
        date {
                match => [ "date_end", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                target => "date_end"
        }
        date {
                match => [ "date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                target => "date"
        }
    }
}
```

When testing this with stubbed out stdin/stdout:

```
input {
 stdin { codec => json }
}
// above filter{} block here
output {
  stdout { codec=>rubydebug}
}
```

And testing like this:

```
echo '{ "startDate": "2015-05-27", "endDate": "2015-05-27", "request" : {"requestId":"123","field2":1,"field2": 2,"field3":3} }' | bin/logstash -f test.conf
```

It outputs this:

```
{
     "startDate" => "2015-05-27",
       "endDate" => "2015-05-27",
       "request" => "{\"requestId\"=>\"123\", \"field2\"=>2, \"field3\"=>3}",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2017-02-09T14:37:02.789Z",
          "host" => "xxxx"
}
```

So I've answered your original question.  You should ask another question if you can't figure out why your template isn't working.

Comment: I updated the topic - added part of my config file. How can i add what you've advised my into this config?

Comment: you'd just add it as another filter after the existing `ruby {}` filter you have

Comment: could you please show it? I've added it as an another filter{} with ruby{} after the first one and got - Configuration error. Not restarting. Re-run with configtest parameter for details

Comment: updated my answer because it wasn't working in logstash 5.1 when I tested it.

Comment: i've updated my config file, but received the same result as in topic...(

Comment: it should be working.  The error you are getting from elasticsearch indicates it didn't replace the field.

Comment: i've updated the topic adding my full configs.. could you please check it?

Comment: Your current problem is not what your originally asked for, so you should ask another question

Comment: now i understand it. Can you help with original question - how to prevent parsing a field if its value is a json?

Comment: That's what my answer currently reflects

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch analyzes the field by default.
If what you need is just not to analyze the `request` field, change how this is indexed by setting `"index": "not-analyzed"` in the mapping of the field.

More info from the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/mapping-intro.html#_index_2)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i've already tried using 'not_analyzed' and not to specify config for this field in ****.template file... there is still the same problem (updated the topic)